Are "I promised him to do the housework" and "I promised him that I would do the housework" similar or the same?
We can use these structures "somebody 1 + want + to + verb 2". and "somebody 1 + want + somebody 2 + to + verb 2".
I guess the subject of "verb2" is "somebody 2"
For example,
-"I wanted to do the housework" (the subject of "do the housework" is "I")
-"I wanted him to do the housework" (the subject of "do the housework" is "him" which is the object of "want")
Now, from the dictionary, we can say "somebody 1 + promise + to + verb 2" (eg "I promised to do the housework"), but I could not find any structure "somebody 1 + promise + somebody 2 + to + verb 2" though it does have the structure "somebody 1 + promise + somebody 2 (that) + a clause".
For example, "I promised him that I would do the housework".
Dictionaries seldom explain how to use the verb.
Are "I promised him to do the housework" and "I promised him that I would do the housework" similar or the same?
If not, then why "I promised him that I would do the housework" works but not "I promised him to do the housework".

You don't promise someone that they will do something, so 'I promised him to do the housework' would automatically mean 'I promised him that I would do the housework', but it would be awkward and ambiguous, and label the speaker as having poor English.

You're not confusing "housework" from "homework", are you? Not that it makes a world of difference  but just in case...

@Mari-LouA, I was supposed to use "chores"

@MichaelHarvey, why is 'I promised him to do the housework'  ambiguous? You have not answered that.

Housework is perfectly fine, then.

"Want" is a modal, which get special patterns. It shouldn't be surprising that "promise" doesn't follow the same patterns; neither do lots of verbs.

You can say "He promised me the world" as in I would not be denied of anything.

Note that 'I promised him (John) to do the housework' is not an idiomatically valid English utterance. But having said that, I wouldn't mind betting that if forced to assign it a meaning, probably most native Anglophones would say (assuming it came from another native Anglophone) that it meant the speaker promised a third party that John would do the housework for them, whereas most non-native Anglophones would probably assume it meant the speaker promised John that he (the speaker) would do John's housework.

I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about the "meaning" of an artificial utterance that's not idiomatically valid in English.
